# Accessing dataframes within a nested list

Tags: r, list, dictionary, nested, purrr

I have a list of three different types of datasets, with ten datasets in each type.  It looks like this:

```
mat1 <- replicate(n=10,data.frame(matrix(data=rnorm(20,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)),simplify=FALSE)
mat2 <- replicate(n=10,data.frame(matrix(data=rnorm(20,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)),simplify=FALSE)
mat3 <- replicate(n=10,data.frame(matrix(data=rnorm(20,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)),simplify=FALSE)
combined <- list(mat1,mat2,mat3)
```

I want to apply the same function to each of the datasets, but I can't figure out how to access them.  I tried using map from purrr, but it only applies it to the first one in the list:

```
map(combined[[i]],~length(.))

[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 5

[[6]]
[1] 5

[[7]]
[1] 5

[[8]]
[1] 5

[[9]]
[1] 5

[[10]]
[1] 5
```

How can I apply a function to all datasets in a nested list?

*The function is more complex than `length` - it's a function from another package that I need to access using `~function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `lengths` on each list in `combined` :

```
lapply(combined, lengths)

#[[1]]
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

#[[2]]
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

#[[3]]
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Using `purrr`'s `map` :

```
purrr::map(combined, lengths)
```

---

If `length` is just an example and you want a general way to apply a function to each nested list you may use nested `lapply` :

```
lapply(combined, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) length(y)))
```

Or use `rapply` :

```
rapply(combined, length, how = 'list')
```

Comment: It's a more complicated function than length - so, unfortunately, lengths doesn't work.  This was just an example.  It's a function from another package that I need to access using ~

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I updated the answer to use nested `lapply` which might help. You can replace `lapply` with `map` if you want to use `purrr`.

Comment: Hmmm... lapply works perfectly for this example - I just have to figure out how to make it work for this function